# HTML5 <nav> centering

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm going nuts a bit trying to do a website but I'm absolutely incapable of center my `<nav>` tag. I've read tons of threads with suggestions that involve putting in the CSS `margin: 0 auto;` or things like `text-align: center` but nothing seems to work.

I have my CSS in a separate file and so, since my CSS doesn't work at all, I'll only put the HTML here:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm using Bootstrap as you can see, and I just want to center it.

Comment: Could you please also include your CSS, too? Your HTML seems okay. (except that you forgot to close the `nav` tag, but I assume that's just the way you posted it here)

Answer (score 7):

Tons of ways, but here's the easiest.  **Three** things are needed for this:

- `display: block;`
- `width` - some amount, can be percentage
- `margin: auto;` - the top/bottom can be whatever

Also note that `<nav>` defaults in browsers as a block-level element, so the first line isn't needed unless in IE 8 or below.

See example below

```css
nav {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Correct. Just as a nav is probably a child element, you do not necessarily need an explicit width set for it, you can go with the inherited value.

Comment: Ok but that code makes my bar too small, and with a percentage it doesn't "really" center it on a page, just centers it a bit more lol.

Comment: And I haven't included the CSS because I deleted it all because I was frustrated with all the stuff that wasn't working hahahaa

Comment: Oh and with inherit as a value it puts it directly on the left, it's not centered at all anymore

Comment: whatever code you have in front of you right now would be helpful so we can re-produce your issue

Comment: And finally, probably your easiest method if you're still having issues.  This will automate it for you - http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do:

```
nav {text-align:center;}
nav ul {display:inline-block;}
nav ul li {display:inline-block;}
```

Alternatively:

```
nav {text-align:center;}
nav ul {display:inline-block;text-align:left;}
```